# is there anyway to fix the find() iteration in javascript that gives me unexpected result?

Tags: find

im trying to find the index value of the array that will show the first occurence of the test but it gives me an unexpected result.

this is my code:

```
const findn = [12,2,3,41,4,67,43,34]
let searchforover = findn.find(findoverf);
function findoverf(value,index,array)
{
   return value > 18;
}
console.log(searchforover);
```

the result is 41:

but im expecting 34, this is really wierd array sequence
is there any way to fix this without changing the array sequence?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are expecting 34? 41 is the first element in the array that is > 18
Perhaps you need to sort the array before you find the first element that is > 18?